# Backbone view delegateevents won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having an issue with getting delegateEvents to work.

here's my View definition:

```
//the "." in Mustache templating simply means it will iterate through an array of JSON objects
var locationViewTemplate = '<div class="ui-content-panel ui-content-panelLocationView ui-corner-all "><div><ul class="ui-content-list">' +
'{{#.}}' +
'<li><span>{{Name}}</span> <a href="#">edit</a></li>' +
'{{/.}}' +
'{{^.}}' +
'<li>No Locations Defined</li>' +
'{{/.}}' +
'</ul></div><input type="text" id="locationName"> <input class="locationAdd" type="button" title="Add Location" id="locationAdd" value="Add"></div>';


//module: Location
(function(Location) {
//define Model
Location.LocationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.entityName = 'location';
    }
});

//define collection
Location.LocationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Location.LocationModel,
    initialize: function () {
        this.entityName = 'location';
    },
    getAllLocations: function () {
        this.functionName = 'GetAll';
        this.fetch();
    }
});

//define View(s)
Location.LocationListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #locationAdd': 'addClickEvent'
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(Mustache.render(locationViewTemplate, this.collection.toJSON()));
        //this.delegateEvents();

        return this;
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        //this.delegateEvents();
    },
    addClickEvent: function (){
        alert('this is the function');
    }

});


})(vHub.module('location'));
```

Here's the definition of the button that the selector '#locationAdd' should find:

```
<input class="locationAdd" type="button" title="Add Location" id="locationAdd" value="Add">
```

I also call delegateEvents from the document ready event:

```
//steal the JS libs that we need
steal('json2.js','mustache.js','underscore.js', 'jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js')
.then('backbone.js')
.then('./common.js')
.then('./modules/FrameTop.js', './modules/Location.js')
.then('./modules/AdminBasicsPage.js')
.then( function() {
$(function(){
initializeApp();

var Location = vHub.module('location');
var lc = new Location.LocationCollection();
lc.getAllLocations();

var lv = new Location.LocationListView({collection: lc});

$('#content').html($(lv.el).html());


});
});
```

I've looked at what i could find here on stackOverflow, and tried some of those suggestions.  But none have been successful yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you call `delegateEvents` at all?  The stock jQuery `delegate` function handles future insertions without being re-called.

Comment: That's a good question.  And I may try that as Plan B.  'delegateEvents' does use jQuery's 'delegate' function, so theoretically, it should be the same is using 'delegate'.

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  When you initialize a view, `delegateEvents` is called automatically.  You don't need to call it yourself unless you completely destroy the element and rebuild it for some weird reason.

Comment: oh I see what you're saying.  Well, it didn't work without calling `delegateEvents` at all either.  I don't know if it's how I have the `events` property defined or what.  I'm kind of stumped. :-/

Comment: @ElfSternberg: And if you do that you should call [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny you should ask... I just solved a similar problem in an app I'm working on, and lo and behold, this was the top question under the Backbone.js tag.

Not sure that we were having the same issue, but my problem was that the button I was trying to attach to was actually outside of the scope of my view. Backbone views have an `el` property, and `click` events are only attached to children of that root element.

In my app, I had a list view which had a `ul` as it's root element. Both my button and the list were siblings inside of a `div` tag:

```
<div>
    <ul id="my-list-view"></ul>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

My code worked initially because I set up the click handler using a raw jQuery selector in the `initialize` function. I was actually reaching outside of the scope of my view and attaching the click handler, which wasn't at all my intention. When I refactored to try to make it fit the Backbone convention, it failed to fire.

Try using a regular jQuery selector in your code, and if it works, you probably have a similar scoping problem. Like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    $('#locationAdd').click(addClickEvent);
    this.render();
}
```

That's not the Backbone way of doing this--you want to use the `events` hash like you have done in your code. But you may need to nest your collection view inside of a control-level view.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I was keeping everything in scope.  I'm on vacation so I don't have my code in front of me at the moment.  Once I get back to the office, I'll take a closer look and mark this as answered if that indeed was the case.

Comment: So, I kind of got this working.  I think there is some scope issue going on.  But i'm having trouble getting `.on()` (no backbone.js even) to work unless the selector exists (which, from my understanding you should be able to in jquery 1.7 and beyond).  This is what worked, even though I'm not completely satisfied: `$('#content').on('click', '#locationAdd', function(){alert('what the...');});` where `#content` is an existing div tag on my HTML page.

Comment: Any chance you could repo this in a jsFiddle or create a GitHub repo? I'm pretty sure we can solve this for you, but it's hard to follow here.

Comment: ACtually, Just figured it out, above I have 
`var lv = new Location.LocationListView({collection: lc});

$('#content').html($(lv.el).html());`,but when it changed it to this: `var lv = new Location.LocationListView({collection: lc, el: $('#content')});` everything worked as it should.  It seems like the events don't get set up correctly when you let Backbone create the default `div` or i wasn't using that div correctly or something.  But when I specify the el when I instantiate it, everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I took what I could from the code you posted and [here](http://db.tt/03MGsMFP) is a little working example. If you want to post more code I could possibly help debug. As Elf mentioned, no need to explicitly call `delegateEvents()`.

Comment: Thanks @tomswift!  I really appreciate the example.  I looked at your example and it looks like i'm doing all the right things.  I updated my code samples in the original post to be more complete, basically copying my JS files.